# jQuery - Loop through parent div, get bottom position of last child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to loop through parent divs and get the bottom position of the last child div.

```
<main id="swipe-page">
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragend-page">
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
        <div class="page-content"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The bottom position of the last page-content div will then be set as the total height of the parent dragend-page div. How would I do this?

```
$.each($('.dragend-page'), function(i, dragend_page) {
    $('.page-content', dragend_page).each(function() {
         var p = this.position();
         console.log(p.bottom);
     });
})
```

This is getting the bottom position of all child divs - not just the last one. And the position function must be incorrect because it's returning "this.position is not a function"

Comment: Try .page-content:last as the selector. Then you don't need the each call either. Position is the correct function, but inside an each you'd need to do $(this) as it's a jQuery function not a Dom function.

Comment: And this.position() should be $(this).position()

Answer (score 2):

as @Rudi mention in comments https://api.jquery.com/position/ returns an object containing the properties top and left .. so you can use this

```
$('.dragend-page').each(function(i, dragend_page) {
    var lastDiv = $(this).find('.page-content:last-child');
    var bottomPosition = lastDiv.position().top +  lastDiv.outerHeight(true);
    console.log(bottomPosition );

})
```

this code will output the bottom position of last .page-content in each .dragend-page

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/position/ returns an object containing the properties top and left.

Comment: thanks @Mohamed-Yousef. I then add $(this).height(p); to change the parent height, but it's not changing as I move to the next slide. $("#swipe-page").dragend({
   afterInitialize: function() {
     this.container.style.visibility = "visible";
   },
   onSwipeEnd: function() {
    var next_slide = parseInt(this.page) + 1;
    window.location.hash = "slide="+next_slide;
    $('.dragend-page').each(function(i, dragend_page) {
     var lastDiv = $(this).find('.page-content:last-child');
     var p  = lastDiv .position().top +  lastDiv.outerHeight(true);
     $(this).height(p);
    })
   }
    });

Comment: @steeped I think you need to run that code twice .. one in onSwipeEnd and  one after $(document).ready() .. I meant try to use that code outside .dragend({

Answer (score 1):

[this](http://jsfiddle.net/t8603L3d/1/) will give you the position of the last div without looping through the divs

```
$(function(){
    console.log($(".dragend-page :last-child").last().position());
});
```